# Using $where in sharded collections

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Does it possible to use `$where` in sharded collections with all advantages of sharding in cluster?

Comment: Yes but it will do a veeeerrry slow scatter and gather operation

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "all advantages of sharding in cluster"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can use `$where` on a sharded collection. The question is if you *should*.

The `$where`-operator should generally be avoided, because it is quite slow and must be executed for every single document in the collection, unless you combine it with some other operators which can use indexes and radically reduce the result set before it is processed by `$where`.

When possible, try to fulfill your requirement with [the other operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/#query-selectors) or with [aggregations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/).